# Android Material Component global style for Material Button, Material Text Button and Material OutlinedButton

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-jetpack, material-components-android

Currently I am using `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0` library.

I have created Base Theme and added Material Button global style like: `<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Material.BaseAppTheme.Button</item>`. It is applied to all default Buttons. Now the problem is I want a specific style for **Material Text Button** and **Material Outlined Button**. But default style is overriding specific style even if I adding specific style in  property. 
Lik this:

```
 <Button
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton" 
    ...>
```

Stil it is showing as the default button. So I have to remove the global button style in Base Theme and adding style in every . I don't know is it the only way to apply styles for a different type of Material Buttons. Or I am missing something.
Here is my Theme and Styles Code

**BASE THEME**

[image]

**BaseTheme.Button and TextAppearance Style**

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Base.Button" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/font_family_regular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@string/font_family_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?buttonTextColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>


<style name="Material.BaseAppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/_8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/_8dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?buttonColorEnabled</item>
</style>
```

**Buttons in XML**

```
              <Button
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_footer_cta_left"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.footerLeftTitle}"
                    app:invisibility="@{viewModel.footerLeftCTAVisibility}"
                    app:onSingleClick="@{() -> viewModel.navigateTo(viewModel.footerLeftCTAUri)}"
                    tools:text="MANAGE ACCOUNT" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tv_footer_cta_right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.footerRightTitle}"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    app:invisibility="@{viewModel.footerRightCTAVisibility}"
                    app:onSingleClick="@{() -> viewModel.navigateTo(viewModel.footerRightCTAUri)}"
                    tools:text="MANAGE ACCOUNT" />
```

**Current Result**

[image]

** Expected Result**

[image]

Comment: I also tried theming recommended by Material.IO https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons/#theming-buttons .  By defining different Theme overlays solved the problem of not overriding but now setting textApppearence in Theme overlays not applied.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct (but use `backgroundTint` instead of `android:background`). Are you using something `tv_footer_cta_left.setChecked(true)` ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I have already tried backgrounfTint in style and in button with no luck. No I am not using .setChecked(true/false)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some help in understanding the material theming.
First changing your application theme to material theme will automatically theme all the buttons in your project (no need to do any additional thing).
Second, you can use

```
 style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
```

in your button code to make your button text only button like in the expected result.

You can read this documentation of material design here : [material.io](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#using-buttons)

the documentaion will really help you, trust me.

Comment: Please read my problem once again and check the code, I have already tried what you are saying. Still, it was not showing textButton. I don't know it was bug in material design or something else.

Comment: did u tried using latest version of material design ?